# Fullscreen Hulu in Firefox minimizes when I browse on another window

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash, fullscreen

I would like to browse on my main monitor while watching a full-screen video. Two separate Firefox windows. closes full screen with other programs as well. Basically how do i force full-screen to remain that way while using other windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving full screen mode when focus changes is a feature of the Flash plugin under Linux.  There is no setting to change this behaviour, and it seems likely that it won't ever get fixed given that Adobe is pulling back on development of the plugin.

Comment: That is a shame thank you for the answer. Is there a work-around?

Comment: Not that I know of.  They changed the behaviour in the Windows version of the plugin (as a way to improve multi-monitor support, since you are more likely to want to do something else while playing something in full screen), but didn't change the Linux version.  Given its proprietary nature, there is a limit to what you can do about this.